# repeat first observation for each id

Tags: r, transformation, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset as follows

```
 Obs#      Id          Date              Med          Dosage      Result
  1        1567        01/03/2011        Acebutol     10mg        100.2
  2        1567        04/02/2011        Acebutol     10mg        98.6
  3        1567        08/14/2011        Oxaprozin    20mg        99.34
  4        1567        08/14/2011        Bayer        20mg        99.34
  5        7845        02/01/2011        Bayer        20mg        89.64
  6        7845        06/14/2011        Bayer        20mg        95.41 
  7        7845        01/06/2012        Bayer        50mg        89.92
  8        7845        01/06/2012        Acebutol     50mg        89.92
  9        7845        04/19/2012        Bayer        50mg        95.15
 10        7845        09/25/2012        Bayer        50mg        99.37
 11        1567        01/14/2012        Oxaprozin    20mg        89.34
 12        1567        05/12/2012        Oxaprozin    20mg        91.4


Test2 <- structure(list(Obs. = 1:12, Id = c(1567L, 1567L, 1567L, 1567L, 
7845L, 7845L, 7845L, 7845L, 7845L, 7845L, 1567L, 1567L), Date =               
structure(c(1L,5L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 7L), .Label =          
c("01/03/2011", "01/06/2012", "01/14/2012", "02/01/2011", "04/02/2011",     
"04/19/2012","05/12/2012", "06/14/2011", "08/14/2011", "09/25/2012"), class      
= "factor"),Med = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("Acebutol", "Bayer", "Oxaprozin"), class = "factor"), 
Dosage = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c(" 20mg", " 50mg", "10mg", "20mg", 
"50mg"), class = "factor"), Result = c(100.2, 98.6, 99.34, 
99.34, 89.64, 95.41, 89.92, 89.92, 95.15, 99.37, 89.34, 91.4
)), .Names = c("Obs.", "Id", "Date", "Med", "Dosage", "Result"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I am using the spread function to transform this dataset as follows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(doBy)
Test2$X <- NULL
Test2$Obs. <- NULL
Test21 = Test2 %>% spread(Med, Dosage, fill = 0)
Test22  = Test21 %>% rename(Date2 = Date) %>% mutate(Date1 = NA)
Test22$Date2 = as.Date(Test22$Date2, "%m/%d/%Y")
Test22 = orderBy(~Id+Date2, data=Test22)

    Id      Date2        Result     Acebutol Bayer    Oxaprozin   Date1
    1567    2011-01-03   100.20     10mg     0        0           NA
    1567    2011-04-02   98.60      10mg     0        0           NA
    1567    2011-08-14   99.34      0        20mg     20mg        NA
    1567    2012-01-14   89.34      0        0        20mg        NA
    1567    2012-05-12   91.40      0        0        20mg        NA
    7845    2011-02-01   89.64      0        20mg     0           NA
    7845    2011-06-14   95.41      0        20mg     0           NA
    7845    2012-01-06   89.92      50mg     50mg     0           NA
    7845    2012-04-19   95.15      0        50mg     0           NA
    7845    2012-09-25   99.37      0        50mg     0           NA
```

What I am trying to do is repeat the first observation for each Id

```
    Id      Date2        Result     Acebutol Bayer    Oxaprozin   Date1

  **1567    2011-01-03   100.20     0        0        0           NA

    1567    2011-01-03   100.20     10mg     0        0           NA
    1567    2011-04-02   98.60      10mg     0        0           NA
    1567    2011-08-14   99.34      0        20mg     20mg        NA
    1567    2012-01-14   89.34      0        0        20mg        NA
    1567    2012-05-12   91.40      0        0        20mg        NA

  **7845    2011-02-01   89.64      0        0        0           NA

    7845    2011-02-01   89.64      0        20mg     0           NA
    7845    2011-06-14   95.41      0        20mg     0           NA
    7845    2012-01-06   89.92      50mg     50mg     0           NA
    7845    2012-04-19   95.15      0        50mg     0           NA
    7845    2012-09-25   99.37      0        50mg     0           NA
```

Not sure how to do this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Pascal, good question, these are the packages I used so far,  `dplyr, tidyr, doBy` I have updated the code with this information

Comment: In your example, the first obs for each ID is repeated with the same ID, Date2 and Result columns, but you seem to be setting the drug columns to 0. Is this what you want or a typo?

Comment: @Gregor, you are absolutely correct, this is per design, not a typo

Comment: Running your example, I get a warning (*Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(ordered), value = 0) : invalid factor level, NA generated*) generated by the `spread` function (`tidyr` version `0.2.0`).

Comment: @Pascal,  , changing column Meds to character should fix this problem,

Comment: It is just to let you know that you may encounter the same waring after upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test22 %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  slice(1) %>% # select the first row of each ID
  mutate_each(funs(set0 = c("0")), 4:6) %>% # recode columns 4-6 as zero
  bind_rows(., Test22) %>% # rbind the new zeroed-out top rows to the original
  arrange(Id, Date2, Result) # sort back to the preferred order

Source: local data frame [12 x 7]

     Id      Date2 Result Acebutol Bayer Oxaprozin Date1
1  1567 2011-01-03 100.20        0     0         0    NA
2  1567 2011-01-03 100.20     10mg    NA        NA    NA
3  1567 2011-04-02  98.60     10mg    NA        NA    NA
4  1567 2011-08-14  99.34       NA  20mg      20mg    NA
5  1567 2012-01-14  89.34       NA    NA      20mg    NA
6  1567 2012-05-12  91.40       NA    NA      20mg    NA
7  7845 2011-02-01  89.64        0     0         0    NA
8  7845 2011-02-01  89.64       NA  20mg        NA    NA
9  7845 2011-06-14  95.41       NA  20mg        NA    NA
10 7845 2012-01-06  89.92     50mg  50mg        NA    NA
11 7845 2012-04-19  95.15       NA  50mg        NA    NA
12 7845 2012-09-25  99.37       NA  50mg        NA    NA
```

Comment: I am having issues with bind_rows function. I am getting an error function bind_rows not found. I uninstalled and reinstalled dplyr , my version of dplyr is 0.3.0.2

Comment: You can replace `bind_rows()` with `rbind()` here and get the same result.

Comment: that worked but I want to apply this on a larger dataset and I am worried that hardcoding rows 4, 6 might cause some issue, `mutate_each(funs(set0 = c("0")), 4:6)`

Comment: If you'd rather specify variable names than column numbers, how about `mutate_each(funs(set0 = c("0")), one_of(c("Acebutol", "Bayer", "Oxaprozin")))` for the `mutate_each` line?

Comment: good point but there are more drugs than these three in the original dataset.

Comment: You'll have to specify column names or numbers, to include or exclude - no way around that.  You could exclude the non-drug columns with `mutate_each(funs(set0 = c("0")), -c(1,2,3,7))`.  At any rate, this is beyond the scope of the original question.  I suggest reading up on dplyr's `select()` to learn your options and posting another question if you get stuck.

Comment: no problem, your suggestions are good, it got me to where I wanted to be....hope I could give you 100 points

Comment: Duplicate and bind the rows *before* spreading and you won't have to worry about how many drugs there are.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
TestNew <- Test22 %>% 
           group_by(Id) %>% 
           arrange(Date2) %>% 
           filter(row_number(Date2) == 1) %>% 
           bind_rows(Test2) %>% 
           arrange(Id, Date2)
```

Comment: @SamThomas, bind_rows function is throwing an error, says function not found. I reinstalled dplyr package and tried but still showing error

Comment: @BridgeportByronTucker Which version of `dplyr` do you use?

Comment: @Pascal, my version of dplyr is 0.3.0.2

Comment: @BridgeportByronTucker If you can, you really should upgrade R and your installed packages.

Comment: @SamThomas, this worked, except there were some non zero values for the meds, no big deal, cool.

Comment: Great, glad that helped.  Thanks for the comment.